# Pycharm auto suggestion doesn't appear after installing plugin intellibot@seleniumLibrary patched

Tags: python, plugins, pycharm, robotframework, intellibot

I have installed PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.6 version

Installed plugin

[image]

[image]

still, I am not getting auto suggestion issue as below,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Remove Intellibot@SelenuimLibrary patched plugin from Pycharm IDE
2. Download latest intellbot.jar file from intellibot github repo and load it in plugins section to install it manually in Pycharm IDE.
   [IntelliJ Repo](https://github.com/mtrubs/intellibot)
3. Restart the Pycharm IDE